# innerHTML working, but removing HTML & head tags

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a sort of email builder. One of the main things needed is the "Download HTML" function to download the email as a whole. To do so, I used innerHTML and it almost works perfectly, but when the new file is saved it removes the  and  tags, which are needed for proper rendering.

Does anyone know how I can include these two tags in my download? Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```html
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js" integrity="sha512-n/4gHW3atM3QqRcbCn6ewmpxcLAHGaDjpEBu4xZd47N0W2oQ+6q7oc3PXstrJYXcbNU1OHdQ1T7pAP+gi5Yu8g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<a style="background-color: #c028b9; color: white; text-decoration: none; padding: 2% 3%; border-radius: 999px" href="#" id="downloadLink">Download email html</a>

    <script>
  function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {
    var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    mimeType = mimeType || 'text/html';

    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType  +  ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
    link.click(); 
}

var fileName =  'emailName_renameMe.html'; 
        
        $('#downloadLink').click(function(){
    downloadInnerHtml(fileName, 'emailPreview','text/html');
});
    </script>
  
        <div id="emailPreviewWrapper" class="emailPreviewWrapper"  style="width: 50%; float: right; position:relative;">
            
        <div id="emailPreview">
       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.ooorg/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http:www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<style></style>
</head>
<table>
<tr>
<td> Email Content</td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.documentElement.outerHTML`

Comment: To preview a full document you should use an iframe instead, what you have there is invalid HTML. But you can simply add the missing tags when you compose the download's text, like this: `var elHtml = "<!doctype html> ..." + document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML; + "</body></html>";`